# ios - for a list of items that can be chosen, should I use pickerview or listview?

Tags: ios, ios5

What it the ui element that should to be used if I just want to create a list of items, and give it some default value?

Also, is there a way to make it only show up on the screen if there are some values that can be found for it?  Meaning...is there a way to only have it show up after some logic in the code says it should be shown?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is vague.

If you are using storyboard, you can create UITableViews with static content that you can define in the storyboard editor by dragging UITableViewCells onto the UITableView and then editing its textLabel values or drag other views/controls onto the cell.

You could toggle the visibility of the UITableView by defining a IBOutlet property, linking it up in storyboard, and changing its hidden property.